# zsh not finding terminal command

Tags: bash, rubygems, zsh

I'm trying to read every line of a file with some gems, for instance this is a line from the `gems.txt`: `active_directory -v 1.6.0`.

```
while read line
do
    "gem dependency $line --remote"
done < gems.txt
```

And I'm getting

```
zsh: command not found: gem dependency active_directory -v 1.6.0 --remote
```

I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Consider write an answer yourself to get this out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the quotes following Cyrus advice and it worked.